# Filter array object by array object with a specific property

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

```js
const arr1 = [
  {id: 1, name: 'first'},
  {id: 2, name: 'second'},
  {id: 3, name: 'third'}
];
const arr2 = [
  {id: 1, name: 'first', color: 'blue'},
  {id: 2, name: 'second', color: 'red'}
];
```

I want to filter `arr1` by property `id` of `arr2`.

The result should be

```js
result = [{id: 3, name: 'third}]
```

I tried:

```js
const arr1 = [
  {id: 1, name: 'first'},
  {id: 2, name: 'second'},
  {id: 3, name: 'third'}
];
const arr2 = [
  {id: 1, name: 'first', color: 'blue'},
  {id: 2, name: 'second', color: 'red'}
];
const result = arr1.filter((item) => {
  return arr2.some((value) => {
    return value.id !== item.id
  })
});
console.log(result);
```

But its result is

```js
[
  {id: 1, name: 'first'},
  {id: 2, name: 'second'},
  {id: 3, name: 'third'}
];
```

I think my logic is almost correct.

Anybody can help with this simple error?

Answer (score 0):

With this approach you need to seach for sameness and exclude on find.

```js
const
    arr1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'first' }, { id: 2, name: 'second' }, { id: 3, name: 'third' }],
    arr2 = [{ id: 1, name: 'first', color: 'blue' }, { id: 2, name: 'second', color: 'red' }],
    result = arr1.filter(item => !arr2.some(value => value.id === item.id));
    //                           ^                            ^^^^

console.log(result);
```